# How can I restore the default background color in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, colors, color-scheme

For a long time I have used a grey background color in Eclipse, and it's awful. But I have really no idea how I can switch back to a default white background.

I have looked in *Window > Preferences* under the *General* and *Java* tab, and tried with *Restore to Defaults* on them, but it doesn't work.

The color settings in Eclipse is a pain.

How can I restore the default background color in Eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefereces -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Appearance dolor options: > Background color

Change to whatever You want or use System Default.

Comment: Thanks, the *System Default* checkbox made it.

Answer (score 0):

**To restore to default white background**

Open menu *Window → *Preferences → General →* Click on Appearance

Click on Restore Defaults and Apply

[Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb2yz.jpg)