# How to restore default color theme in Eclipse Helios?

Tags: eclipse, color-scheme

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96981/color-themes-for-eclipse) question and played with a color theme with dark background. It looks cool in Java editor but not for other editors. Then I tried to use the default color themes by clicking "Restore Defaults" buttons for **ALL** editors in Preference dialog and refering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085618/how-can-i-restore-the-default-background-color-in-eclipse) question. But in the file compare view the background is still black and the differences between compared files are hardly to discern.

Any way I can restore the backgound color in file compare view?

Answer (score 13):

just remove a few lines which are about color in:

```
{workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs
```

then restart your eclipse, that's it.

Comment: for those of you who have a version of eclipse that follows this file structure and who also need to reset the xml editor colors, kill the following file:

{workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.prefs

Answer (score 12):

Kane's solution works. And user can also just delete

```
"...\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings".
```

Then restart Eclipse, do a little bit configuration, you are back to default theme.

Answer (score 10):

I think the answer is here in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96981/color-themes-for-eclipse) mentioned by you. The theme plug-in modified below files under your workspace. You could switch to a new workspace, or remove the preference keys about color/font from those files.

> Essentially there are two files we
>   want to copy or overwrite:
>
> **[workspace].metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs
>   [workspace].metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs**

Comment: Thanks. But it does not work. I have overwritten those two files, and finally all files in that folder, but the Compare Editor still has black background. However it is clear that the settings are somewhere in workspace, but I hava not found out where.

Comment: Aptana broke my Eclipse colors too. This fix worked for me. I looked for "foreground" and "background" in all the files in that folder and switched the "248,248,248" and "20,20,20" values for the respective keys.

Answer (score 1):

To restore `theme to default`, remove only

```
[workspace].metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme.prefs
```

By doing this you will not loose other configurations that you have done,

Like `Python interpreter` settings.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for resetting UI changes left behind by [Darkest Dark Theme](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme) in Eclipse Neon.